# OpenCV Java: how to access coordinates returned by findNonZero()?

Tags: android, opencv

In my android app, I am using `findNonZero()` to find and access white points in a binary image.

I get the image (`binMat`with size: 595*800) as the input to the method and then I have:

```
...
Mat wLocMat = Mat.zeros(binMat.size(), binMat.channels()); 
Core.findNonZero(binMat, wLocMat);
```

The problem is: I don't know how to access the white points' coordinates stored inside the `wLocMat`! when I log the `wLocMat.toString()`, I get this:

```
[ 476000*1*CV_32SC2, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0x74abd920, dataAddr=0x75bac010 ]
```

So, how exactly can I access the coordinates stored in `wLocMat`?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem was initializing the output matrix to the size of the image. I just had to create an empty `Mat` and pass it to the function:

```
...
Mat wLocMat = Mat.zeros(); 
Core.findNonZero(binMat, wLocMat);
```

Then, by converting `wLocMat` to `MatOfPoint`, the coordinates are easily accessible:

```
MatOfPoint mop = new MatOfPoint(wLocMat);
```