# Get white pixels and save it to array in java opencv

Tags: java, android, arrays, opencv

I try to get some white pixel in binary image and save coodinate of pixel to array of matrix 2x1. Something like this:

```
//x  y
//2  3
//7  8
//13 16
//24 26
//78 103
//22 14
//16 18
```

I use opencv in android and get white pixel in binary image and save coodinate of pixel to array to handle. but i don't know how to save it to array and which array in opencv suitable(Matofpoint,MatofPoint2f,MatOfInt...)

here is my code, but it lack

```
        Size BinaryImage_size = BinaryImage.size();
        double[] pixel_white = new double[0]; //just use 1 channel
        MatOfFloat pointPositions = new MatOfFloat();

        for(int i=0;i<BinaryImage.height;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;jBinaryImage.width;j++)
            {
                pixel_white = BinaryImage.get(i,j);
                if(pixel_white[0]>0)
                {
                    // Maybe use it pointPositions.push_back(Point(i,j)); but it wrong
                    //which implementation i should here?
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Question is a don't know how to save coodinate of pixel to array

Comment: you should use `findNonZero()` function.you can find an example usage [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18366103/5294258)